# Android Kotlin calculate pace (time)

Tags: android, time, kotlin

So... I have been around this for 2 days already and it's driving me crazy.

I am trying to make this [layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEZct.png) work. It is supposed to be either a time and/or pace calculator. I am trying one at a time first, but this isn't going well after 2 days.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_running_calculator)

    var distanceView = findViewById<NumberPicker>(R.id.distanceTxtField) as TextView
    var timeView = findViewById<NumberPicker>(R.id.timeTxtField) as TextView
    var paceView = findViewById<NumberPicker>(R.id.paceTxtField) as TextView
    var calculateBtn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.calculateBtn)
    var resultView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView5)
```

//............

```
  fun calculationPaceKm () {

        var stringArray = timeView.text.toString().split(":")
        var total = stringArray[0].toDouble()
        total += (stringArray[1].toDouble() / 60 )
        var distanceValue = distanceView.text.toString().toDouble()
        var resultPaceKm = ((distanceValue / total) * 1.37).toDouble()
        var resultFormatPaceMiles = "%.1f pace".format(resultPaceKm)
        resultView.setText(resultFormatPaceMiles.toString())}

kmBtn.setOnClickListener{

            calculationPaceKm()


            }
```

I don't know how to go around the time... I have been getting very very weird results and nothing is working :/

Thanks

=======================

**EDIT**

So I edited my question so you could see what I have. It is pretty much what you gave me but with some tweaks. What I notices is that it doesn't convert my distance properly and I don't know why. Let's say I convert 7.37Km to Miles. It should give me 4.58 Miles but I get 4.35 Miles, as if I am multiplying by 0.59  which I am not. I am multiplying by 0.621371

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val time = findViewById<NumberPicker>(R.id.time) as TextView
    val distance = findViewById<NumberPicker>(R.id.distance) as TextView
    val pace = findViewById<NumberPicker>(R.id.pace) as TextView




    calculate.setOnClickListener {

        when {

            time.text.isEmpty() && (distance.text.isNotEmpty() && pace.text.isNotEmpty()) ->
                calculatePace(null, distance.text.toString(), pace.text.toString())

            distance.text.isEmpty() && (time.text.isNotEmpty() && pace.text.isNotEmpty()) ->
                calculatePace(time.text.toString(), null, pace.text.toString())

            pace.text.isEmpty() && (time.text.isNotEmpty() && distance.text.isNotEmpty()) ->
                calculatePace(time.text.toString(), distance.text.toString(), null)

            else -> {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please check all fields",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }

}


fun Double.format(digits: Int) = java.lang.String.format("%.${digits}f", this)


@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
private fun calculatePace(time: String?, distance: String?, pace: String?) {


    // KM Distance and KM Pace Button
    if (kmDistanceRadioBtn.isChecked && kmPaceRadioBtn.isChecked)
        when {
        // TIME: To calculate your time, fill in your distance and pace
            time == null -> {
                val calculatedTime = distance!!.toLong() * timeToSeconds(pace.toString())
                result.text = "The runner's time is ${secondsToTime(calculatedTime)}"
            }
        // DISTANCE: To calculate your distance, fill in your time and pace
            distance == null -> {
                val calculatedDistance = (timeToSeconds(time).toDouble().div(timeToSeconds
                (pace.toString()).toDouble())).format(2)
                result.text = "Distance is $calculatedDistance KM"
            }
        // PACE: To calculate your pace, fill in your time and distance
            pace == null -> {
                // Calculate Pace
                val calculatedPace: Long = timeToSeconds(time).toLong() / distance.toLong()

                Log.i("PaceSeconds", calculatedPace.toString() +
                        secondsToTime(calculatedPace))


                result.text = "The runner's pace in KM is ${secondsToTime(calculatedPace)}"
            }
        }

    // Miles Distance and Miles Pace Button
    else if (milesDistanceRadioBtn.isChecked && milesPaceRadioBtn.isChecked)
        when {
        // TIME: To calculate your time, fill in your distance and pace
            time == null -> {
                val calculatedTime = distance!!.toLong() * timeToSeconds(pace.toString())
                result.text = "The runner's time is ${secondsToTime(calculatedTime)}"
            }
        // DISTANCE: To calculate your distance, fill in your time and pace
            distance == null -> {
                val calculatedDistance = (timeToSeconds(time).toDouble().div(timeToSeconds
                (pace.toString()).toDouble())).format(2)
                result.text = "Distance is $calculatedDistance Miles"
            }
        // PACE: To calculate your pace, fill in your time and distance
            pace == null -> {
                // Calculate Pace
                val calculatedPace: Long = timeToSeconds(time).toLong() / distance.toLong()

                Log.i("PaceSeconds", calculatedPace.toString() +
                        secondsToTime(calculatedPace))


                result.text = "The runner's pace in miles is ${secondsToTime(calculatedPace)}"
            }

            // KM Distance and Miles Pace Button
        } else if(kmDistanceRadioBtn.isChecked && milesPaceRadioBtn.isChecked) {
        when {
        // TIME: To calculate your time, fill in your distance and pace
            time == null -> {
                val calculatedTime = distance!!.toLong() * timeToSeconds(pace.toString())
                result.text = "The runner's time is ${secondsToTime(calculatedTime)}"
            }
        // DISTANCE: To calculate your distance, fill in your time and pace
            distance == null -> {
                val calculatedDistance = (timeToSeconds(time).div(timeToSeconds
                (pace.toString())) * 0.621371).format(2)
                result.text = "Distance is $calculatedDistance Miles"
            }
        // PACE: To calculate your pace, fill in your time and distance
            pace == null -> {
                // Calculate Pace
                val calculatedPace: Long = timeToSeconds(time).toLong() / distance.toLong()

                Log.i("PaceSeconds", calculatedPace.toString() +
                        secondsToTime(calculatedPace))


                result.text = "The runner's pace in miles is ${secondsToTime(calculatedPace)}"
            }
        }

        // Miles Distance and KM Pace Button
    } else if(milesDistanceRadioBtn.isChecked && kmPaceRadioBtn.isChecked) {
        when {
        // TIME: To calculate your time, fill in your distance and pace
            time == null -> {
                val calculatedTime = distance!!.toLong() * timeToSeconds(pace.toString())
                result.text = "The runner's time is ${secondsToTime(calculatedTime)}"
            }
        // DISTANCE: To calculate your distance, fill in your time and pace
            distance == null -> {
                val calculatedDistance = (timeToSeconds(time).div(timeToSeconds
                (pace.toString())) * 0.621371).format(2)
                result.text = "Distance is $calculatedDistance Miles"
            }
        // PACE: To calculate your pace, fill in your time and distance
            pace == null -> {
                // Calculate Pace
                val calculatedPace: Long = timeToSeconds(time).toLong() / distance.toLong()

                Log.i("PaceSeconds", calculatedPace.toString() +
                        secondsToTime(calculatedPace))


                result.text = "The runner's pace in miles is ${secondsToTime(calculatedPace)}"
            }
        }


    } else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please choose one unit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }


}

// Convert Time to Seconds
@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
private fun timeToSeconds(time: String): Long {
    val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss")
    val reference = dateFormat.parse("00:00")
    val date = dateFormat.parse(time)

    return (date.time - reference.time) / 1000L
}

// Convert Seconds to Time
private fun secondsToTime(seconds: Long): String {
    val hours = seconds / 3600
    val minutes = (seconds % 3600) / 60
    val seconds = seconds % 60

    return String.format("%02d:%02d",minutes, seconds)
}}
```

Comment: what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: Getting very weird results... I don't know how to work with the time. Tried the math you're seeing but it doesn't work.

Comment: what is the result you are getting and what are you expecting?

Comment: Double checking

Comment: For instance.. If I put 10Km distance and 10:00 (minutes and seconds) the result should be 1:00 (the pace) and I get 10:00. If I put 11:00 (or 10:60) the result should be 1:06. Although on my app I get 1:25 :/

Comment: What you want as output ? Pace per KM ? What are inputs ?

Comment: What do you mean? Perhaps it is simple to explain the end goal. The end goal is for the user to always input the distance (first plain text); then either input the time he wants to finish it in (second plain text) which will give him the pace (how fast does he have to run/walk). OR, put the pace(third plain text) instead of the time and receive on how long he has to do it.

Comment: Any ideas on what the problem might be? :)

Comment: I understood what you want working on it give me few minutes

Comment: Thanks. DO you want the full code @RajeshDalsaniya ?

Comment: Nope I will provide you logic you can add in your code later on.

Comment: I managed to calculate Pace working on other part. Hold on for few more minutes.

Comment: Of course. I noticed for some reason this doesnt work: var total = stringArray[0].toDouble()
            total += (stringArray[1].toDouble() * 0.60) 

It does not multiply my number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep field empty which you want to calculate.

**MainActivity.kt**

```
        package com.example.wave18.pacecalculator

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.TextView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    // Regex for Checking Input time Format
    val regex = Regex("^([0-1]\\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\\d):([0-5]\\d)\$")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val time = findViewById<View>(R.id.time) as TextView
        val distance = findViewById<View>(R.id.distance) as TextView
        val pace = findViewById<View>(R.id.pace) as TextView


        calculate.setOnClickListener {

            when {


                time.text.isEmpty() && (distance.text.isNotEmpty() && pace.text.isNotEmpty()) -> {

                    if (regex.matches(pace.text)) {
                        calculatePace(null, distance.text.toString(), pace.text.toString())
                    } else {
                        // SHOW ERROR
                    }


                }

                distance.text.isEmpty() && (time.text.isNotEmpty() && pace.text.isNotEmpty()) -> calculatePace(time.text.toString(), null, pace.text.toString())

                pace.text.isEmpty() && (time.text.isNotEmpty() && distance.text.isNotEmpty()) -> calculatePace(time.text.toString(), distance.text.toString(), null)

                else -> {
                    Log.i("Error", "Something wrong You need to enter / empty values")
                }

            }
        }

    }


    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private fun calculatePace(time: String?, distance: String?, pace: String?) {


        when {
        // TIME: To calculate your time, fill in your distance and pace
            time == null -> {
                val calulatedTime = distance!!.toLong() * timeToSeconds(pace.toString())
                result.text = "The runner's time is ${secondsToTime(calulatedTime)}"
            }
        // DISTANCE: To calculate your distance, fill in your time and pace
            distance == null -> {
                val calculatedDistance = timeToSeconds(time).toDouble().div(timeToSeconds(pace.toString()))
                result.text = "Distance is $calculatedDistance KM"
            }
        // PACE: To calculate your pace, fill in your time and distance
            pace == null -> {
                // Calculate Pace
                val calculatedPace: Long = timeToSeconds(time).toLong() / distance.toLong()

                Log.i("PaceSeconds", calculatedPace.toString() + secondsToTime(calculatedPace))


                result.text = "The runner's pace is ${secondsToTime(calculatedPace)}"
            }
        }
    }

    // Convert Time to Seconds
    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    private fun timeToSeconds(time: String): Long {
        val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss")
        val reference = dateFormat.parse("00:00:00")
        val date = dateFormat.parse(time)
        val seconds = (date.time - reference.time) / 1000L

        return seconds
    }


    // Convert Seconds to Time
    private fun secondsToTime(seconds: Long): String {
        val hours = seconds / 3600
        val minutes = (seconds % 3600) / 60
        val seconds = seconds % 60

        val timeString = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds)
        return timeString
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.wave18.pacecalculator.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="107dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="62dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="87dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="01:10:10"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/distance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="106dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="63dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="10"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/time" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/pace"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="107dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="62dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/distance" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pace" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/calculate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="165dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="131dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="61dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/result" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Try this `val calculatedDistance = timeToSeconds(time).toDouble().div(timeToSeconds(pace.toString()).toDouble())`

Comment: it worked! just need to format it to two decimals! wow thanks. Can you explain it to me, as in why it works? Thanks

Comment: We converting time to Seconds threw function which returning Long Value and we don't assign any type for calculatedDistance by default for that reason wrong result was coming. What we did here we converted both value to double to .32023 all value preserved after . (dot) in division process and stored in calculatedDistance

Comment: If answer is right for you then mark as answered thanks :)

Comment: Thanks just did. Just one last thing: why do when I do the calculation for the time/pace the result rounds down ? so, If I put 1min:37s for 10km distance, the pace should be 00m:10s but my calculator gives me 00:09

Comment: Its round off issue

Comment: Creates a type conflict in Log.i and result.text. I tried to passs .toLong on them so the error would go away but it doesn't o.O

Comment: so that can't be fixed?

Comment: You need to look in   // Convert Seconds to Time function I cant look in more right now working on other stuff

Comment: Morning Rajesh. I just noticed that actually the code you gave me doesn't work properly. The converter has a problem. Mind having a look? I can show you what I have tried. Thanks\

Comment: I am bit busy will look in it by end of this week

Comment: So I edited my question so you could see what I have. It is pretty much what you gave me but with some tweaks. What I notices is that it doesn't convert my distance properly and I don't know why. Let's say I convert 7.37Km to Miles. It should give me 4.58 Miles but I get 4.35 Miles, as if I am multiplying by 0.59  which I am not. I am multiplying by 0.621371